# Autohotkey: WinGet cannot find window with WinTitle as txt, but can with a.txt

Tags: autohotkey

I opened a window whose part of title is a.txt and I use AutoHotKey to find it.

```
WinGet, p_txt, ProcessName, txt
WinGet, p_atxt, ProcessName, a.txt
ListVars
```

It shows when search criteria is txt, p_txt has no value; when criteria is a.txt, p_atxt has value.[image]

Why can `WinGet, p_atxt, ProcessName, a.txt` find my window but `WinGet, p_txt, ProcessName, txt` cannot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching behavior if window titles is determined by [SetTitleMatchMode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm).

Amongst others, there are these modes:

**1**: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.
**2**: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.
**3**: A window's title must exactly match WinTitle to be a match.

`SetTitleMatchMode, 2` is what you're looking for.

Comment: The default match mode is 1, that is why txt cannot match. I see.